# File location of kernel extensions?

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-extensions

Is there an easy way to make the mapping from kernel extension to the file it came from?

I can get the list of currently loaded kernel extension via `kextstat`. This gives me the bundle names, like `com.AmbrosiaSW.AudioSupport` or `jp.plentycom.driver.SteerMouse`. But how can I then find the actual file locations of these bundles? For example, the Ambrosia bundle is `AmbrosiaAudioSupport.kext`, and I can only find the bundle name in the `Info.plist` inside that bundle. I could grep the `/System/Library/Extensions/` directory, but [this does not necessarily contain extensions loaded after booting](http://daringfireball.net/2003/08/the_one_and_only_mac_os_x_extensions_folder), and I assume there is a better way to do it?

Comment: You want to use `KextManagerCreateURLForBundleIdentifier` as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197383/locating-bundles-by-identifier which gives you the path for a kext no matter where it's loaded from. It's used in objective-see's app https://objective-see.org/products/kextviewr.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use `kextfind -b <bundlename>` to find the file defining a kext you only know the bundle name of.

**EDIT:** *newer versions of kextfind need a `-print` predicate to show output. Example updated below.*

For example:

```
kextfind -b com.AmbrosiaSW.AudioSupport -print
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( -

```Mac-Pro.local ➜  Extensions  kextstat | grep rehab
   18    0 0xffffff7f8131f000 0x4000     0x4000     com.rehabman.driver.USBInjectAll (0.6.5) A63DACD5-10FE-3A1C-BCB1-4EEF5308B7CC <13 12 5 3>
Mac-Pro.local ➜  Extensions  kextfind -b com.rehabman.driver.USBInjectAll
Mac-Pro.local ➜  Extensions
```

Comment: @RomanGaufman newer versions of kextfind need a `-print` predicate to show output, else it will just return true if the bundle is found. I have updated the answer accordingly

Comment: FWIW I didn't need the `-print` option on macOS 13.1

Answer (score 4):

See [kextfind](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/Articles/command_line_tools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009455-SW2)

Comment: `kextfind` is interesting, but it seems it only searched in the standard `/System/Library/Extensions/` folder. Is there a way to find the location of bundles that were not loaded from this folder? Something that remembers the `-r` parameter of `kextutil`?

Comment: @JanFabry Yes, see my comment to OP's post.

Answer (score 1):

Try About this mac -> System report -> Software section -> Extensions.

It shows the filepath upon selecting an extension.